# Meteor-mongo server access remotely

Tags: mongodb, meteor, tizen

I have a full stack project on http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:3000, Its a meteor- application, with mongo database.
And I am also want to create another application, with pure html/css/js, and my question. Can I access to my full stack project's database with 2.nd project? (With my second application I want to get the users playlists, what is a collection)
I would be also gladdy if you could explain me, how can I access to it.

Comment: In production you are anyway forced to install a mongodb somewhere because the mongodb shipped with Meteor is only for dev purposes and is not used in production mode. So you need to install a mongodb anyway. This can then also be connected with your other app as long as it has the correct packages to connect to a mongodb.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was so usefull for me.